Formal Framework for Time-Reversal Symmetry in Quantum Mechanics
Usually when we think of symmetries in Quantum Mechanics we think of some group $G$ and a representation $\rho$ of that group on the physical Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ of the system we are interested in. One could then ask whether the Hamiltonian posseses this symmetry, i.e. if $H$ commutes with all $\rho(g), g\in G$, or maybe if a given state $|\psi\rangle$ belongs to a certain irrep of that group.
But, I'm wondering what the correct framework would be when one wants to consider time-reversal. Obviously, there is no action of time-reversal on states from $\mathcal{H}$ directly, for it only does something to the trajectories generated under a Hamiltonian. Yet, one often writes something like $|\psi\rangle\rightarrow T|\psi\rangle$, or $A\rightarrow TAT^{-1}$ for operators. What's the formal way to go about this? E.g. in the above case, what's the formal definition of $T$?

Time-transversal? Or time-reversal?

Formally speaking, by Wigner's theorem, symmetries of quantum systems should be represented by unitary or antiunitary bijections on $\mathcal{H}$ (of course we identify them up to a phase). By some rather technical arguments, one can show that it must be antiunitary, c.f. prop 2.1. https://d-scholarship.pitt.edu/12533/1/B_Roberts.pdf .

yeah sorry, I meant time-reversal. My bad

Galindo and Pascual (Vol. 1) have a nice discussion. But any decent quantum mechanics book should discuss symmetries, and also time-reversal symmetry. Which books have you checked already? What exactly is not clear?
